# How can I use my C# class in my XAML file in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following C# class:

```
public class Appointment
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

I pass an object of this class when an item is tapped in a alistview as follows:

```
private async void ListAppointments_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item is Appointment appointment)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new CheckAppointmentDetails(appointment));
            }
        }
```

And the code-behind of my CheckAppointmentDetails class:

```
public partial class CheckAppointmentDetails : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly Appointment appointment;
        public CheckAppointmentDetails (Appointment appointment)
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            this.appointment = appointment;
        }
    }
```

Now I want to know how can I use the properties of my appointment object in the CheckAppointmentDetails XAML file so I could show the properties in a label, for example:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Source=appointment, Path=Name}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can only data bind to public properties.  You also need to set the BindingContext for the page

```
public partial class CheckAppointmentDetails : ContentPage
{
    public Appointment appointment { get; set; }

    public CheckAppointmentDetails (Appointment appointment)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        BindingContext = this.appointment = appointment;
    }
}
```

then in the XAML

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding appointment.Name}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Its still not working, the {Binding } doesnt show the appointment as an option

Comment: Have you actually tried running it?  Or are you just saying it doesn't show in Intellisense in the editor?

Comment: 1) is your BindingContext set correctly?  2)  is  "appointment"  a public property on the class assigned to  BindingContext?  3) is "Name" a public property on Assignment?  4) be sure spelling and casing are correct in your binding path

Comment: Found the problema, Its <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/> since its already Binded to Appointments